# Get tr element with document.querySelector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

I trying to get a tr element using the `document.querySelector` sentence, but I get :

```
TypeError: tempNode.querySelector(...) is null
```

My selector in Javascript is: `document.querySelector("#row-model")`
This is working with other element (with a div to be exact) but with it, I tried others selectors (using the datatype, the tr, etc, but always I get the same error)...Then in the browser console I checked the existence of the element, the HTML of the element is as follows:

```
<table>
        <tbody>
    <tr class="" id="row-model" data-id="myid" data-type="rowtemplate">
        <td class="category">
            <a href="" title="Go to category" id="category"></a>
        </td>
        <td class="title  showTipTip">
            <a data-cats="" href="#profile" id="title" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" title="" data-id="" class="spotlink" address="true"></a>
        </td>
        <td class="comments">
            <a class="spotlink" href="#comments" title="" id="commentValue"> commentValue
            </a>
        </td>

        <td class="genre">
            <a href="" title="Search spot in category" id="genre"> catdesc</a>
        </td>
        <td class="poster">
            <a href="" title="Search spot from " id="poster">poster</a>
        </td>
        <td class="date" id="since"></td>

        <td class="filesize" id="filesize">

        </td>
        <td class="nzb">
            <a href="" title="Download NZB (n)" class="nzb" target="_blank" id="nzbdownload">NZB</a>
        </td>
        <td class="multinzb">
            <input onclick="multinzb()" name="messageid[]" value="" type="checkbox">
        </td>
    </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**EDITED:**

The JS code inside the function is:

```
 $('#catalog').each(function(){
        var tempNode = document.querySelector("#row-model").cloneNode(true); //I clone the element and then append it to another table
       tempNode.querySelector("a #category").textContent = "test";
      $('#spotsTable tr:last').after(tempNode);
    });
```

Also, I have the table inside a div with hidden class (bootstrap), maybe it can affect it?

Comment: Are you referencing the row before it is rendered to the page? How do you call the code?

Comment: @epascarello no,it's inside a function that I call when the user push a button and the content is already loaded

Comment: what is tempNode ?

Comment: We need more context

Comment: can you the js code?

Comment: Where do you get tempNode?

Comment: You are trying to get the only tr with querySelector, but it has an id...? And your using jQuery... Confused.

Comment: @allnodcoms I have that tr as a template, then I can fill it with correct data and add it to the table, I made it because I dont want to create the element with javascript

Comment: from nothing it started to work now, thank you everyone!